# Not able to render two canvas elements on same page - Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, canvas

```
<div class="col-lg-5" id="id-sales-pie">


</div>

<div class="col-lg-7" id="id-sales-line">



</div>
```

MainChartView

```
    this.line.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-line')).delegateEvents().render();
    this.pie.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-pie')).delegateEvents().render();
```

I have a main chart view that contains the two id's and the main chart view contains two views the PieChartView and LineChartView.

both the views have templates however when rendering only one renders and the other canvas element gives an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

Complete Code:

```
 var $ = require('jquery'),
    Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    mainchartTemplate = require('../../templates/dashboard/chartscontainer.html'),
    pieChartView = require('../../views/dashboard/PieChartView'),
    lineChartView = require('../../views/dashboard/LineChartView'),
    moment = require('moment');

var MainChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#id-charts-stats'),

    initialize: function() {

        this.pie = new pieChartView();
        this.line = new lineChartView();



    },
    events: {
        'click a.agraphType': "changeGraphData"
    },

    changeGraphData: function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var type = $(ev.target).attr('type');

        sessionStorage.setItem("typeOfGraph", type);


        this.render();

    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(mainchartTemplate);

        if (this.line) {
            this.line.remove();
        }

        this.line.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-line')).delegateEvents().render();

        if (this.pie) {
            this.pie.remove();
        }

        this.pie.setElement(this.$('#id-sales-pie')).delegateEvents().render();



    }
});

module.exports = MainChartView;
```

it doesn't render the second setElement code for me when the page renders for the first time.

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle? with the info you shared its hard to tell

Comment: i put my main view code i cannot create a jsFiddle as it uses Browserify